# Popup on click add to cart button in woocommerce

Tags: jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to show a popup with some basic information like product name,  image, pricing and cart total after clicking Add to cart button in woocommerce. I use this following code to trigger a popup but I don't know how to call the product information.

```
<div id="after_add_to_cart_popup">
  <input type="hidden" id="product_id__" name="product_id_name">
  <h1>Popup</h1>

  <span id="close_add_to_cart_popup">close</span>
</div>
```

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

        $(document).on('click', '.add_to_cart_button', function (e) {
         $("#after_add_to_cart_popup").show();
            
          var id = $(this).data('product_id');
          $("#product_id__").val(id);

            $("#close_add_to_cart_popup").click(function () {
                $("#after_add_to_cart_popup").hide();
                $("#product_id__").val('');

            })

      });
    });
```

Comment: How are you adding this code to your site?

Comment: Basically I'm developing a custom wordpress theme, So want popup when anyone click on add to cart link, so this jquery code if found to trigger the popup but i have to use AJAX to load the clicked product information and cart total value, unfortunately i'm getting confused how to do that. ( I use this code in footer )

Comment: How are you inserting the `after_add_to_cart_popup` html?

Comment: I use this html code in footer as well. Popup is working properly just need to load the product information.